# How to set RingCentral hold music?

Tags: ringcentral

RingCentral has the ability to upload custom Hold Music via the UI. Can this be done via the API, as user and as an admin for other users? Searching the [API Reference](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference) for hold music didn't turn up an API.

Here's some info on this functionality:

- User: https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/1798
- Admin: https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/8360

Here's what the UI looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps to this:

1. Get the Answering Rule ID of the rule you want to change. This can be a standard rule such as `business-hours-rule`, or it can be a custom rule that you have created. You can call the **Get Call Handling Rules API** to get a list of current standard and custom rules.
2. Call the **Update Greeting API** with `type` set to `HoldMusic` and `answeringRuleId` set to the id you wish to update, e.g. `business-hours-rule`

There are actually several ways to call the Update Greeting API:

1. `multipart/form-data` with individual string parts. In this approach, separate parts are sent with names `type`, `answeringRuleId`, and `binary`
2. `multipart/form-data` with JSON metadata part. In this approach, a JSON MIME part named `json` is sent with a payload like: `{"type": "HoldMusic", "answeringRule": { "id": "12345678" }}`
3. `multipart/mixed`

I tend to prefer the first approach (`multipart/form-data` with individual string parts) because it's easy to use with tools like cURL and many HTTP clients.

Here's an example using Go:

```golang
package main

import(
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"

    "github.com/grokify/gotilla/mime/multipartutil"
    "github.com/grokify/oauth2more/ringcentral"
)

func main() {

    // Get the Client (*http.Client):
    client, err = ringcentral.NewClientPassword(
        ringcentral.ApplicationCredentials{
            ClientID:     os.Getenv("RINGCENTRAL_CLIENT_ID"),
            ClientSecret: os.Getenv("RINGCENTRAL_CLIENT_SECRET"),
            ServerURL:    os.Getenv("RINGCENTRAL_SERVER_URL")},
        ringcentral.PasswordCredentials{
            Username:  os.Getenv("RINGCENTRAL_USERNAME"),
            Extension: os.Getenv("RINGCENTRAL_EXTENSION"),
            Password:  os.Getenv("RINGCENTRAL_PASSWORD")})
    if err!=nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Create the HTTP Request (*http.Request)
    params := url.Values{}
    params.Set("type", "HoldMusic")
    params.Set("answeringRuleId", "business-hours-rule")

    req, err := multipartutil.NewRequest(
        http.MethodPost,
        "https://platform.ringcenral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/greeting",
        params,
        []multipartutil.FileInfo{
            {
                MIMEPartName: "binary",
                Filepath:     "mygreeting.wav",
            },
        },
    )

    // Send the request
    resp, err = client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("STATUS: %v\n", resp.StatusCode) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [ringcentral](/questions/tagged/ringcentral) API for creating custom user greeting and set greeting type as **HoldMusic**
https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Rule-Management/createCustomUserGreeting

[Create custom user greeting API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwzgD.jpg)